# Why is my comman navigation darwerlayout and content.xml overlapping each other

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Question: Why my common navigation drawer layout and content.xml is overlapping each other

I want to implement common navigation drawer for all the multiple activities by using include. I have created a separated  XML file for navigation drawer and also include toolbar code inside it.

[image]

[image]

#### Navigation.xml

This the navigation part where we include toolbar and drawer code.so here we are implementing simple navigation code by using drawer layout and recycle view

```
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_Drawerlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:openDrawer="start">

            <include
                layout="@layout/navigation_drawerlayout" />

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_View"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <include layout="@layout/navigation_headerview" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:id="@+id/navigationRecycleView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        Toolbar.xml
        this the common toolbar for all the activities.the most uses of it we can easily reuse the code.in which I've simply use CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout inside it use toolbar layout with a title.so that I can show toolbar title with a toolbar.

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

                    <!-- Screen title -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></TextView>
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        contents.xml
        this the content file where we define my code logic and implementation and also similar to all the activities which use the common navigation drawer

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context=".Activities.EventsActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/toolbar"
            >

            <!-- Events -->
            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:id="@+id/events_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please help me to out to this issue

Comment: Please check question is edited

Comment: see the code so can better understand what i want  to do